# How do I counter 1. e4 e5 2. Qh5?

Tags: strategy, tactics

I am a new player and a particular move that I have encountered multiple times playing as either black or white is:

```
[FEN ""]
1. e4 e5 2. Qh5 g6 3. Qe5+ Be7 (3... Ne7 4. Qh8+) 4. Qh8+
```

This was the mistake I made the first time I encountered this and needless to say, I have never played g6 (or b3) since. However, this strategy is still very worrying and I have found myself losing my rook multiple times. When a bishop or a knight are added, my pawn line is breached before I could shore up my defense. What is this opening called and how should I try countering it?

Comment: This line and its refutation is covered in in existing thread: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/23028/how-to-deal-with-your-opponents-queen-if-your-opponent-rejects-any-trades

Comment: Thank you! I found what I was looking for. By the way, would this be called the Patzer opening?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my answer over there. [Miodrag Perunovic once tried to defend this open under the name Patzer opening](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g72vgnwU6TU).

Comment: I think this question is a more direct duplicate of this one: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/18418/countering-the-wayward-queen-attack

Comment: @Akavall It appears so. But I don't think I can change which question mine is a duplicate of.

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, I don't think you can do it. I just added the other question because it was relevant, and maybe somebody ( a moderator?) can modify the list of duplicates.